# How do I get the django HttpRequest from a django rest framework Request?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to use the [django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/messages/) to show messages after `ModelViewSet.create()`:

```
class DomainModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def create(self, request):
        super(DomainModelViewSet, self).create(request)
        messages.success(self.request, "Domain Added.")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: add_message() argument must be an HttpRequest object, not 'Request'.
```

So, how can use the Django `HttpRequest` from django rest framework `Request`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I went thru the source code and found my answer while typing out the question.

Django REST framework has a `Request` keep the `HttpRequest` (or at least one compatible with django messages) in a `_request` property. So, this works:

```
messages.success(self.request._request, "Domain Added.")
```

Comment: it throws ```django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream```